# SQL to Get Last Six Month Sign Up Data

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking at getting certain data from our user sign-ups. We have data from 2013 up to now, but I need data from the last six months of how many users have signed up each month.

I don't know where to begin with starting the SQL query as what I have done so far is all wrong and doesn't come up with what I need.

I have a `c_date (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)` column with the dates the user signed up.

All I have managed to do is get the data for a single month

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(c_date) AS total
FROM
    accounts
WHERE
    c_date BETWEEN '2017-05-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-05-31 23:59:59'
```

**I am using MySQL**

Comment: I think you need a function to extract the current year and month from c_date. Then you can group by that function. In Oracle with a date column it would be something like to_char(c_date,'YYYY-MM'). But, I'm not sure what sort of database you are using.

Comment: I am using MySQL

Comment: Hi, 
You can use this conversion for your c_date field: 
    `DATE_FORMAT(c_date, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2017/05/01' AND 2017-05-31'`
or simply
    `DATE(c_date) BETWEEN '2017/05/01' AND 2017-05-31'`

To retrieve the date for your timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your SQL flavor, I would suggest using the `current_date` [SQL keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql) and the `interval` [datatype](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/interval-data-types):

```
where c_date >= current_date - interval '180 day'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  I don't know what system you're using but here is how you might do it in SQL Server.  This sums up the counts by month and year

     select datepart(month, c_date) as month, datepart(year, c_date) as year, count(*)as total
     from accounts
     where c_date > dateadd(month, -6, getdate())
     group by datepart(month, c_date), datepart(year, c_date)
     order by month desc
```

Comment: What's the MySQL equivalent of these date functions?

Answer (score 0):

You want to aggregate the data.  Something like this:

```
SELECT YEAR(c_date) as yyyy, MONTH(c_date) as mm, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM accounts a
WHERE c_date >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL (1 - DAY(CURDATE())) )- INTERVAL 6 MONTH
GROUP BY yyyy, mm;
```

The `WHERE` clause calculates the first day of the month starting six months ago.

Comment: Not sure if this is for MySQL? I get syntax error after the last ')'

Comment: @ChrisMellor . . . Missed the parens around the second `CURDATE()`.